# Should we remove correlated columns BEFORE or AFTER converting to dummy vars?

Tags: correlation, data-preprocessing

I would like to know your insights / opinions, about what is good approach:

**MAIN QUESTION:**
Remove highly correlated columns BEFORE or AFTER converting nominals to dummy variables?

The difference in final dataset can be quite huge, because:

- converting to dummies can create many columns (often having many same numbers / zeros), that can be strongly correlated and removed.
- on other, removing these columns can skew / break the logical concept of
  converting nominals to dummies

**Imagine common situation in life of data-scientist**

1. we are doing predictive regression like [Kaggle House Prices](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques#evaluation)
2. prepare basic steps for data cleaning & preprocessing

   1. setting correct column types
   2. imputing missing values
   3. removing ID columns
   4. convert nominals + ordinals to numbers
   5. optionally remove outliers
   6. optionally fix skewed distributions to normal
   7. optionally remove strongly correlated columns

**The goal** is making most accurate predictive model = to train model with smallest error on test set.

Removing correlated variables can help in many models - especially in linear regression models

**I google'd a lot** and I can give myself one simple answer:

- Let's try both (decorrelate before / after dummies) and compare results

This is completely practical and valid answer, but it is quite general and applicable almost everywhere :)

So I am looking for more insights / experiences / opinions of skilled people.

**In most data-science tutorials online**, the steps are in this order:

1. decorrelation
2. conversion to dummies - is executed after decorrelation

**I am curious:**

1. why it is so common to see doing it in this specific order (decorrelation first, to-dummies next)?
2. why it is not done in opposite order? - because conversion to dummies could bring many new correlated columns into the dataset again?

Comment: What is the goal of your analysis, and why does it necessitate removing correlated variables?

Comment: Need much more to opine, but happy to do so.

Comment: A strange question. If you are removing some of dummies this means you are - depending on the type of your subsequent analysis - either deleting categories from the nominal variable or merging the "deleted" categories in one. So, why the decision what to do with separate categories of nominal variable X should depend on some variable Y? I'm not to say it's illegal, only that it must have a special reason for.

Comment: Yes, I have same feeling it is a strange question :) Maybe it is good to ask: In case  - conversion to dummy variables creates correlated columns - should we remove them ? What if correlation is so strong, that it creates almost same or strongly correlated columns - is one of them redundant?

Comment: "Removing correlated variables can help in many models - especially in linear regression models"  Not if you're interested in prediction.  I'm not sure where you read this is true, but it is false.